# Get type of Key and Value from a Map variable?

Tags: dart, types, typechecking

Given a `Map` variable, how can I determine the type of Key and Value from it?

For example:

```
void doSomething(Map m){  
  print('m: ${m.runtimeType}');
  print('keys: ${m.keys.runtimeType}');  
  print('values: ${m.values.runtimeType}'); 
  print('entries: ${m.entries.runtimeType}'); 
}


void main() async {
  Map<String, int> m = {};  
  doSomething(m);
}
```

This will print

```
m: _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, int>
keys: _CompactIterable<String>
values: _CompactIterable<int>
entries: MappedIterable<String, MapEntry<String, int>>
```

But how can I get the actual type of Key and Value (i.e. `String` and `int`), so that I can use them in type checking code (i.e. `if( KeyType == String )`)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extract the type parameters of a class if it doesn't provide them to you, and `Map` does not.

An example of a class which does provide them is something like:

```dart
class Example<T> {
  Type get type => T;
  R withType<R>(R Function<X>() callback) => callback<T>();
}
```

If you have an instance of `Example`, you can get to the type parameter, either as a `Type` (which is generally useless), or as a type argument which allows you to do anything with the type.

Alas, providing access to types variables that way is very rare in most classes.

You can possibly use reflection if you have access to `dart:mirrors`, but most code does not (it doesn't work with ahead-of-time compilation, which includes all web code, or in Flutter programs).

You can try to *guess* the type by trying types that you know (like `map is Map<dynamic, num>`, then `map is Map<dynamic, int>` and `map is Map<dynamic, Never>`. If the first two are true, and the last one is false, then the value type is definitely `int`. That only works if you know all the possible types.
It does work particularly well for platform types like `int` and `String` because you know for certain that their only subtype is `Never`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can depend on the *static* type instead of the runtime type, you could use a generic function:

```dart
Type mapKeyType<K, V>(Map<K, V> map) => K;
```

Otherwise you would need to have a non-empty `Map` and inspect the runtime types of the actual elements.